# NSParameterAssert and BOOLs

Tags: objective-c

I have a method that takes a BOOL parameter and I want to make sure it is not nil in the call.

```
-(void)setNetworkFilterWithName:(NSString *)nameOfFilter toState:(BOOL)newState
```

I can't use a `NSParameterAssert(newState);` because it will assert when the BOOL is false.

So I do this:

```
NSParameterAssert((newState == true) || (newState == false));
```

Is there a more elegant way of checking for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BOOL` is a value type, not a pointer so it can not be `NULL`. It will only be false which is zero or not false which is non zero. No need to check it.

**Edit:**
If you would like to check and make sure that the `BOOL` is `YES` or `NO` that could prove useful especially in situations where an `NSNumber` is accidentally passed, which will always evaluate to true if it is not nil.

NSParameterAssert(!newState || newState == YES);

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I am trying to be defensive for incorrect types being passed in so this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A BOOL is just an integer; it has no notion of "not valid" or "unset", the way that objects have nil. 0 is false, and anything else is true. The parameter assert you have written cannot possibly throw an assert: ((newState == YES) || (newState == NO)) is always true. You cannot do what you want using a BOOL. You could convert to using an NSNumber, which, as an object type, allows you to pass in nil and check for it.

EDIT: I am incorrect about the evaluation of the expression ((newState == YES) || (newState == NO)); if you are outside the range provided by YES and NO (that is, newState is something other than 0 or 1) then while it will evaluate to either "true" or "false" in the C sense, it will *not* be equal to either YES or NO. (newState || !newState) is always true in C, but ((newState == YES) || (newState == NO)) is only always true if you can be sure newState holds the values YES or NO and no others. Thanks to Joe for pointing out the error.

Comment: That statement about `== YES` and `== NO` is not entirely true. You said   your self that `BOOL` is just an integer (not to be confused with int)  so consider this: `BOOL abool = 6;
 
 if(abool == YES)
  NSLog(@"It is Yes");
 if(abool)
  NSLog(@"It evaluates to true");` "It is Yes" will never be printed.

Comment: Direct comparisons between `BOOL` variables and the `YES` constant should be avoided for the reasons @Joe mentioned.